# Gulp Build command is failing with error " EISDIR: Illegal operation on directory"

Tags: gulp

I am trying to run the gulp build task for the dev environment on the server but its failing. However, The same gulp build is working on my local machine. The function and error are given below.

Function:

```
// S3 Upload for dev
gulp.task('s3sync:dev', function () {
var config = {
    accessKeyId: "-Key-",
    secretAccessKey: "-Key-"
};

var s3 = require('gulp-s3-upload')(config);

  return gulp.src("./dist/**")
    .pipe(s3({
        Bucket: 'example',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }, {
        maxRetries: 5
  }))
});
```

Command:

```
Gulp build:development
```

Error:

```
[09:01:04] Starting 's3sync:dev'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, This problem has been solved by removing a system symlink which was created after the deployment from the capistrano which is also running  below npm commands.

```
npm run clean && npm run build
```

After removing the system file. I have run the below command and it works fine.

```
gulp build:development
```